# how to use jotm with jpa and neo4j

Tags: spring, jpa, neo4j

I configured my application based on spring,jpa and neo4j to use JOTM for transaction management with the following configuration.

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="jotm" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.JotmFactoryBean"/>
 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
```

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase"
    destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${neo4j.dblocation}" />
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <map>
            <entry key="TXMANAGER_IMPLEMENTATION" value="spring-jta" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean> 

<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" /> 
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"  transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

But I am facing with two instances of the class org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager: jtaTransactionManager, neo4jTransactionManager.

And my log :

Using JTA UserTransaction: org.objectweb.jotm.Current@81e88
Using JTA TransactionManager: org.objectweb.jotm.Current@81e88
Using JTA UserTransaction: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.UserTransactionImpl@6cc760
Using JTA TransactionManager: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.SpringTransactionManager@195ab57

Is my configuration correct and which one should  use?

Thank you

Comment: When you say you're using JPA with Neo4j, which JPA implementation ? because the only one I know of is DataNucleus JPA. "Spring Data Neo4j" is not JPA.

Comment: yes your are rignt i use spring data neo4j; but i use also jpa/hibernate to read/write in my data base MySQL